# Not to clear textbox on page reload or button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have developed a website in `C# asp.net` which contains a `Master Page`.
I have designed a top menu with Search bar(`txtSearch`) and a `Button`(`LinkButton`).
When I click on `search Button` it redirects to the page where searched data is to be displayed but when it redirects it clear's the `txtSearch`. 
What I want is not to clear the `txtSearch` on page redirect or page reload.

> Top Menu (Search bar)

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control" Placeholder="Search term..." />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSearch" CssClass="btn btn-default" type="button" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>
</span>
```

I Hope that the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is.. Store the `TextBox` value in Session in `onclick()` Function

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session["TextBoxVal"] = TextBox1.Text;//The particular TextBox that has value
}
```

and onPageLoad just assign the value to the `TextBox` value like this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
            TextBox1.Text = (string)ViewState["TextBoxVal"];
       }
         //use this as per your needs just an example how to use
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = (string)ViewState["TextBoxVal"];
        }
    }
```

and once it is assigned value to the `TexBox` clear the session or it will keep assigning the same value.. do it like this

```
Session["TextBoxVal"] = null;
```

Comment: How to add that that value back to txtSearch(of master page) from Search.aspx page ? @Frost_Mourne

Comment: Same  TextBox1.Text = (string)ViewState["TextBoxVal"];
 session can be used in any page of the Solution. just give the proper TextBox Id and u can use it

Comment: I know that Session value can be retrieved in any page but how to retrieve the textbox(txtSearch of Master Page) ??

Comment: (string)ViewState["TextBoxVal"]; this just gives u the string which u previously saved u can give it to everything that can hold data u can give it to even label.Text= (string)ViewState["TextBoxVal"];  or anyother element

Comment: Thank you for the Help @Frost_Mourne I used like this and it worked completely fine.

if(Request.QueryString["keyword"] != null && Request.QueryString["keyword"] != "")
                {
                    txtSearch.Text = Request.QueryString["keyword"].ToString();
                }

Comment: You are Welcome

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass data to another page.to pass data you can use various techniques

- Query string
- Session
- Cookies

pass data using above one method.

i will suggest Query string will be best option

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515199/passing-values-between-pages) for passing data

Comment: Thank you for the help. It worked 

if(Request.QueryString["keyword"] != null && Request.QueryString["keyword"] != "")
                {
                    txtSearch.Text = Request.QueryString["keyword"].ToString();
                }

Answer (score -1):

You must pass value in querystring in between pages to persist it.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Or maybe post it as a comment.

Comment: I am passing the value of txtSearch in query string but how to add that that value of query string back to txtSearch(of master page) from Search.aspx page ? @Vijay Raheja

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515199/passing-values-between-pages) for passing data

Comment: Thank you for the help it worked 

if(Request.QueryString["keyword"] != null && Request.QueryString["keyword"] != "")
                {
                    txtSearch.Text = Request.QueryString["keyword"].ToString();
                }

Comment: If you still have your code not running, then post your code so that i could look in.

Answer (score -1):

put it on a session:

```
Session["Sample"] =null;
```

Comment: While this might work, It's far better to add details explaining you answer. You can find more tips here: [answer]

Comment: @ItamarGreen is right and it seems that u are copying my answer.Because I have already given the same solution in detail

Comment: @Frost_Mourne I think you're the first person I see with 101 rep that's **not** from assoc. bonus XD