# Dynamic Response.Redirect to previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a "thank you" page that is shared by two different forms pages. What I want to do is depending on what the original page was, have the `Response.Redirect` populate the previous page's url after a period of 4 seconds.

I'm not sure how to go about grabbing the previous url to put into the redirect, possibly through reflection? I've gotten this far:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
    Response.Redirect("some sort of dynamic code");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the HTTP Referrer in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258217/getting-the-http-referrer-in-asp-net)

Comment: tried HttpRequest.UrlReferrer?, i think it's the cleanest

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PreviousPage property. This can tell the web form that sent you to the thank-you page. You'll need to add a few settings to the top of the .aspx page in order to set this up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do this client-side, if you want to show something from the server. You can provide the page you want to direct to via a `asp:HiddenField`, and then load that value in javascript and redirect.

Something like:

```
var redirectUrl = document.getElementById("myRedirectUrlHiddenFieldID");
setTimeout(function() { window.location = redirectUrl; }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As this one says very analytically : [Suggested solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956027/how-to-pass-values-across-the-pages-in-asp-net-insted-of-session)

there are several ways to accomplish this. In brief:

1) `Request.QueryString["SomeParameter"].ToString();`

2) `this.Context.Items["Parameter"].ToString();` and  `Server.Transfer("somePage.aspx", true);`

3) Posting form to another page instead of PostBack

4) Adding PostBackURL property of control for cross page post back.

Choose your best one and try it.