# Session vs static Property in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, properties

I wanted to use some data from one page to another. General solution is to use `Session` (most of recommends). My boss don't like sessions and he suggested me to do same work by using `C# Property` in common class as below

```
public static long parentId { get; set; }
```

and set it one one page as

```
Common.parentId = "any value";
```

and use it on other page like

```
string anyVariable = Common.parentId
```

and it worked. We get rid of session expiration as well. But why most of people recommend session. Is property another state management thing?

Comment: If you don't care about the values shared being across all sessions you can use static properties.

Comment: Is it a `static` variable in the `Common class`? If you you are doing it wrong because all the user will get the same value. It's better to use `Session` or [pass the values from one page to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956027/how-to-pass-values-across-the-pages-in-asp-net-insted-of-session#14956100) while navigation which is very difficult to control.

Comment: If it's temporary you can use the AppCache to store the object, plenty of docs on how to use it, you can store the data with an ID (maybe the user or a page reference) and then pull it out on the page.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ sharing a variable across multiple user means? If I open my application from two browser and running set code in one and get code from another, will I get the same value that is set by other browser?

Comment: @Imad yes if value is all ready set then old value will be lost. the previous user will see the update value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to store some data using simple static property you must understand that it will be shared among all your users. Sessions are not for this. But I don't see any reasons not to use sessions if you want to store user data somewhere.

In my project it is very convenient, especially when we use SQL-server to store sessions - we can update our website without any losing users' sessions data.
You can check all possible ways to hanle sessions for example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100).aspx