# how we can pass value to aspx page from asp page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vbscript

I am in a situation where I want to set value to a variable from an asp page and retrieve this variable value in aspx page .I understand sending the values through `querystring` is not a best option.

Please help me .

Comment: Maybe you should explain why passing the value by queryString is not an acceptable solution for you

Comment: aspx page to asp page? or aspx page to aspx page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956027/how-to-pass-values-across-the-pages-in-asp-net-insted-of-session

Comment: I can't pass value as query string because value is an email id,I need to pass this email id from asp page to aspx page .

Answer (score 1):

It is better to encrypt the value and send it in querystring.

or

if the value is based on loggedin user or role, you can save it in database and retrieve it in other page using the same user or role.

Comment: Its based on logged user,but we can,t use database because its a forgot password section ,the forgot password functionalities are defined in asp page , if the user forgot the password a new password is send to user email .this email id get fom a textbox control in asp page and that  email id is which i want to display in aspx page.

Comment: If the forgot password asp page is within the iframe window of the aspx main page, you can use javascript ie you can assign any variable in the parent widow from the iframe - parent.email= txtEmail.value;

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable via cookie