# How to retain the value in form using Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI to design the registration form, my registration process having five steps where I need to navigate to different pages to complete the registration process. So, how to retain user entered value in form while navigating to different page till the registration process to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if you staying on the same page and only the script change or you actually moving between pages

But you could

1. store in the url - encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(object_to_be_serialised))
2. @Viewbag

depends on your server side, but judging from kendo it is c#

```
[http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/passing-data-between-pages-in-asp.net.htm][1]
```

[jQuery mobile example](http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/)

[or use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956027/how-to-pass-values-across-the-pages-in-asp-net-insted-of-session)