# Passon json object from one page to another in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms

I am two page and i need to pass certain data as json object to other page.

**Page1.aspx Code**

```
obj.Name= "My Name";
obj.Age= 30;
obj.Country= "Japan";
.....
.....
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

Response.redirect("Page2.aspx");
```

**Page2.aspx**

How can i pass this information to page2.aspx when i do a redirect.

One way i can do it to pass it as form object in one of the hidden fields and then deserialize it.

I was wondering if there is another easy way.

Comment: Querystring if it is not too long. Maybe on base64

Comment: That is my concern. It could be long specially in case of multilingual.

Comment: Ok, maybe you could use a session variable. And send a dynamic key on querystring

Comment: why you don't use session for this?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Response.redirect("Page2.aspx?MyJson=json");
```

And in "Page2.aspx" read the values:

```
string FromJson = Response.QueryString["MyJson"].ToString();
```

Comment: I am concern about the length of the object. For now i am passing as a hiddenfield

Comment: @Learning You can have a look at [pass values across the pages in ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14956219/3796048)

Comment: if the json size in big you can save the json file on disk and retrieve it on another page. and can pass the name of the file in the `redirect`

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use a session variable.

```
obj.Name= "My Name";
obj.Age= 30;
obj.Country= "Japan";
.....
.....
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

Session["json"] = json;

Response.redirect("Page2.aspx");
```

Then get values using session on your page2.aspx

Comment: Isn't it better to pass json object as a vlue in hidden field, just in case session timesout

Comment: It's depend on the project requirements.